# How do I use openupgradelib to update from odoo15 to odoo16?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

When I try to update odoo from v15 to v16 (running in a docker environment) via [openupgradelib](https://github.com/OCA/openupgradelib) I encouter two problems:

1. some modules like account isn't migrated into the new database
2. and in general the new database is as described as possibly not compatible with the new version 16

I have provided all necessary modules and run the update with the following command (parameters): `-c ou_15_16.config --save --database odoo16 --upgrade-path=/mnt/extra-addons/openupgrade_scripts/scripts --load=base,web,account,openupgrade_framework --update all --stop-after-init`

I'm using postgres 15.4 to store the database. Am I missing something? I get no errors while the upgrade is running only a list of successfull migrated modules. And no message that some modules like account aren't migrated and I don't see them in the new database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure, but it seems the migration for upgrades to V16 is not ready, yet.

https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade/issues/3681

Comment: Yeah, thought the same. Additionally, the upgrade has to be run from the new odoo version, in my case odoo16. I thought I have to start it from the old version. I will try that.